# a questionabout three.js when i use trackballcontrols.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i try to use trackballcontrols.js  in my project but need some modification,and i cant understand these code  ,can you give me some explanation？

```
var getMouseOnCircle = ( function () {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

    return function getMouseOnCircle( pageX, pageY ) {

        vector.set(
            ( ( pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / ( _this.screen.width * 0.5 ) ),
            ( ( _this.screen.height + 2 * ( _this.screen.top - pageY ) ) / _this.screen.width ) // screen.width intentional
        );

        return vector;

    };

}() );
```

Comment: What modification do you need?

Answer (score 0):

This code converts the coordinate of the mouse position into the normalized 2d vector (to use it for rotation calculation).

[image]

Comment: ok, i know the  **X**  ,but  this code  `( ( _this.screen.height + 2 * ( _this.screen.top - pageY ) ) / _this.screen.width ) ` to get **Y**, i am  very confused

Answer (score 0):

The method expects to be passed the mouse's XY coordinate on the global screen. It returns the X component linearly interpolated between -1 and 1 and the Y component linearly interpolated between -a and a, where a is the "aspect ratio" given by the viewport height divided by the viewport width.